# What happens when a charged capacitor is connected to an uncharged capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, capacitance

I had this doubt about what would happen when a capacitor of capacitance $C_1$ with a charge Q was connected to an uncharged capacitor of capacitance $C_2$.

I took to researching this question in Google and found answers in several places.

However every answer talked about Kirchoff Voltage Law, which I could not understand or relate, till I realised that the connection that I meant and what the answers meant was different.

The answers meant that the capacitors were connected to each other at both the ends.

However what I want to know is what would happen if they were connected only at one side and the other side was left unconnected.

I felt like there should be a difference but I'm not that sure about the consequence.

Please help if you can!

And if you require more clarification you can comment and I'll clarify the question more.

Answer (score 1):

If capacitor $C_1$ has charges $\pm Q_1$ on each plate and $C_2$ has charges $\pm Q_2$ on each plate, connecting one terminal of $C_1$ to one terminal $C_2$ results in no charge transfer.

You need to *complete the circuit* by connecting both ends (i.e. connecting the capacitors in parallel) if there is to be a charge transfer. Otherwise, each capacitor must maintain equal and opposite charge on both plates, which only happens if there is no charge flow.